# Import additional python files in main python file which is used in spark-submit of databricks

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have created a databricks in azure. I have launched a workspace and a cluster in it.
I have placed the main python file in databrick filesystem. 
**dbfs:/FileStore/tables/read_batch.py**

This read_batch.py has imported another python files from directory called *my_util*.
Usage in)

> from my_util.apps_config import crct_type_list

I have placed the apps_config.py inside *my_util* directory which is parallel to the main python file read_batch.py. i.e *my_util* directory is also present inside dbfs:/FileStore/tables.

When i try to create a spark-submit job in data bricks, i am getting the following error,

```
ImportError: No module named 'my_util'
```

What is the correct way to run this spark-submit job in databricks **without** making all the contents into a single large python file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I zipped the dependent files and uploaded it. I have imported the contents zip files in main python file using,

> import sys 
>    sys.path.insert(0, jobs.zip)

Included the zip file during spark submit using ***"--py-files jobs.zip"***.
Refer the following link, which talks about the best practices for spark submit.
https://developerzen.com/best-practices-writing-production-grade-pyspark-jobs-cb688ac4d20f